# Why is $bslt undefined?

Tags: php

With the following Code I am getting a notice that $bslt is an undefined variable.  Could someone help me understand what I have done wrong?

```
  $log = file("log.csv");
  for ($i=1;$i<=100;$i++){
      $each = explode(',',$log[$i]);
      $data = explode(' ', $each[12]);
      $bslt .= $data[1] . ', ';
  }
```

However, if I `var_dump($bslt)` I will get a string with all the data it holds.

Comment: what is the output you get if you try `echo $each[12];` soon after ine 4?

Comment: if today this was an array, you could do `$bslt[]=$data[1]` no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not initialised $bslt. It is trying to append the contents of $data[1] to an uninitialised variable.

Add `$bslt = ""` before the for loop

Answer (score 1):

First initialize `$bslt` variable.

```
$bslt = ""
$log = file("log.csv");
  for ($i=1;$i<=100;$i++){
      $each = explode(',',$log[$i]);
      $data = explode(' ', $each[12]);
      $bslt .= $data[1] . ', ';
  }
```